# Can not access BIOS setup on Acer E1-522 after changing it to legacy

Tags: boot, bios, acer-aspire

I purchased an Acer E1-522 and the default Linux OS was not working. As I was planning to install Windows 7, I put the DVD in the drive, changed boot preference to the DVD drive and rebooted the computer. But it still tried to load the default Linux installation. So, I changed the boot system from something to Legacy. After that nothing works. Even pressing `F2` does not enter BIOS setup. How can I get it back?

Comment: "Nothing works" is not a very good problem description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I pressed 'F2' and hold it for few seconds until it entered BIOS.

Comment: @DavidPostill That is the solution. On legacy boot mode on Acer E1-522, you need to press `F2` or `F12` and hold it until the BIOS Setup or Boot Menu appears.